# Remote connection to host machine from remote machine, what happens?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Just out of curiosity.  What would happen if I connect remotely to a Windows pc, and then from that remote pc remotely connect back to the original machine?  Is this how black holes are formed, or would I just get an error that I can't connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the software.  If you are talking about Remote Desktop, you will just get dropped from your original session.

I.e. you are on PC-A connecting to PC-B.  From your session in B you try to connect back to A.  Once you do this and enter your credentials, your session on A will be overridden by the new remote session from B and you will get dropped.